# Why is reloading a flutter webview causes runJavascript to not work?

Tags: flutter, webview

im using the flutter_webview library and loaded a script that generates a svg file. There is a next page button in the js so I can go to the next page in the document. This works normally after I load in everything as seen below.

Code doing the next page action:

```
                widget.webViewController
                    .runJavaScript("nextPageClick()")
                    .whenComplete(() => print("next complete"))
                    .onError(
                  (error, stackTrace) {
                    print(error.toString());
                    print(stackTrace.toString());
                  },
                );
                widget.reportController
                    .setCurrentPage(widget.reportController.page + 1);
                buttonClick = "next";
                setState(() {});
```

This works normally, but after I called reload() for the webview, this nextPageClick did not even get registered at all.

nextPageClick:

````
        function nextPageClick() {
            // console.log(Date.now().getSeconds().toString() + ":" + Date.now().getMilliseconds().toString());
            Print.postMessage('<?php Print(pass); ?>');
            if ($('.report-viewer-btn[title="Next Page"]').attr('disabled') != 'disabled')
                $('.report-viewer-btn[title="Next Page"]').click();
        }```
````